# Encode AttributedString with custom attributes to JSON

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, codable

Swift 5.5 introduced `AttributedString` conforming to `Codable` however this is not working for me as I'd expect.

Take the following example:

Here I define a custom attribute `TextCase`

```
public enum TextCase: Codable {
    case lowercase
    case uppercase
}

public struct TextCaseAttribute: CodableAttributedStringKey {
    public typealias Value = TextCase
    public static var name = "TextCaseAttribute"
}

public extension AttributeScopes {
    struct ExtendedTextAttributes: AttributeScope {
        public let textCase: TextCaseAttribute
        public let foundation: FoundationAttributes
    }
    var customAttributes: ExtendedTextAttributes.Type { ExtendedTextAttributes.self }
}

public extension AttributeDynamicLookup {
    subscript<T: AttributedStringKey>(
        dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<AttributeScopes.ExtendedTextAttributes, T>
    ) -> T {
        get { self[T.self] }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
    var hello: AttributedString {
        var result = AttributedString("Hello")
        result.textCase = .uppercase
        result.font = .largeTitle
        return result
    }
```

when I use JSONEncoder to encode the `AttributedString` it gives me the following:

```
po String(decoding: JSONEncoder().encode(hello), as: UTF8.self)
->
"[\"Hello\",{\"SwiftUI.Font\":{}}]"
```

Notice that my `textCase` is missing plus I expected `SwiftUI.Font` to have a value.

Comment: Where is the code to change the case in the attributed string? This doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: @vadian I left out that part as my issue is with decoding the AttributedString, once decoded I'm aware that I'd need to go through the runs and implement custom logic for custom attributes.

Comment: I tried playing around with this. If you simply print the AttributedString then you can see a reference to `TextCaseAttribute` so the problem only seems to be with encoding. I tried explicitly implementing the `encode` function in `TextCase` and it was never called when using `JSONEncoder`. Same with implementing `encode` for `TextCaseAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks @HangarRash, I got it to work by implementing custom encoding/decoding, posting code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing custom encoding and decoding seems to work:

```
struct NonCodableType: Hashable {
    var inner: String
}

extension AttributeScopes {
    enum CustomCodableAttribute: CodableAttributedStringKey {
        typealias Value = NonCodableType
        static let name = "NonCodableConvertible"

        static func encode(_ value: NonCodableType, to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var c = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try c.encode(value.inner)
        }

        static func decode(from decoder: Decoder) throws -> NonCodableType {
            let c = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let inner = try c.decode(String.self)
            return NonCodableType(inner: inner)
        }
    }
}

extension AttributeDynamicLookup {
    subscript<T: AttributedStringKey>(
        dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<AttributeScopes.CustomCodableAttribute, T>
    ) -> T {
        self[T.self]
    }
}

struct UnifiedAttributes: AttributeScope {
    var customCodable: AttributeScopes.CustomCodableAttribute
}

struct CodableType: Codable {
    @CodableConfiguration(from: UnifiedAttributes.self)
    var attributedString = AttributedString()
}
```

print it like this

```
po String(decoding: JSONEncoder().encode(CodableType(attributedString: hello)), as: UTF8.self)
```

Source: Apple `swift-corelibs-foundation` test code here https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Tests/Foundation/Tests/TestAttributedString.swift

still curious why encoding a Codable type won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for NSAttributedString but you can convert it to AttributedString with init function:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682431

You can packing the NSAttributedString in a Codable container, and the container is Data: you can convert the NSAttributedString to Data. Because Data is codable so your custom Struct will able to be codable:

Code to convert NSAttributedString to Data:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
   
    func data() throws -> Data { try 
    NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false) }

}
```

Code to convert Data back to NSAttributedString:

```
extension Data {
    func topLevelObject() throws -> Any? { try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(self) }
    func unarchive<T>() throws -> T? { try topLevelObject() as? T }
    func attributedString() throws -> NSAttributedString? { try unarchive() }
}
```

Add it to your custom Struct and make the whole struct Codable:

```
struct CustomStruct : Codable {
    
    /// NSAttributedString in Data
    var attStringData : Data
}
```

Pack it in a computedVariable for better syntax:

```
extension CustomStruct {
    var string : NSAttributedString? {
        get {
            return attStringData.attributedString()
        }
        set {
            let attData =  newValue.data()
            attStringData = attData
        }
    }
}
```